# Attempting to link two selection form fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

What I am attempting to do is link two selection form fields so when a user selects an option in field A, it updates field B to the appropriate selection. I have been able to get the fields to update by adding a 2 to the selected id which corresponds with the id of the second selection field.

However, I am also doing some calculations based on the values returned. It is telling me that they are non-numeric, which I've verified because the value returned isn't the "value" but the actual text of the selection. So instead of returning option value of 400. It is returning 400W Metal Halide.

So I have the following selection fields:

```
<select id="currentwattage">
    <option val="400" id="id1">400W Metal Halide</option>
    <option val="40" id="id2">40-32W Fluorescent T12/T8</option>
</select>
<select id="ledwattage">
    <option val="120" id="id12">120W LED</option>
    <option val="16" id="id22">16W LED</option>
</select>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
$('#currentwattage').change(function() {
    var selected = $(':selected', this)[0].id + 2;
    $('#' + selected).attr("selected","selected")
        .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');

    var $select2 = $('#ledwattage');
    if(selected == $(':selected', $select2)[0].id) {
        $('#ledwattage').attr('id');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

I appreciate any help available. I am still learning jQuery and realize my code may be very flawed especially after staring at it for hours.

Comment: `<option>` elements don't have a `val` attribute; it's `value`. Ex: `<option value="120" id="id12">`

Comment: Thanks, I completely was focused on the jQuery portion and missed something so simple. Thank you again